# Huawei P8 Lite 2015 soft-bricked and won't turn on or charge

Tags: unbricking, huawei

I got a Huawei P8 Lite (ALE-L21) model that I received from someone. The issue was that it kept booting into this recovery mode phase that kept asking to flash software update again showing two errors.

At first, the phone would charge perfectly, and as soon as it could power on, it quickly jumped to the recovery mode. After a few days later, I decided to come back to the phone but unfortunately, it wasn't powering on. Every time I put it on the charger, it just shows red blinking light once, then nothing happens. Sometimes it would blink red and green on the LED light, but still nothing happened.

I have the full stock ROM of the phone on a memory card (SanDisk class 10) and it's been on the phone for some time but still no luck. I tried leaving the phone on PC all night but I didn't respond.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this phone powered up?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest answer

https://huaweiflash.com/how-to-flash-huawei-stock-firmware-all-methods/

Basically = press the right buttons to get into bootloader or flash mode.

HiSuite = easiest.

SDCARD FILE MODE = meh...

- SP Flash Tool 
  is the most difficult - But you essentially leave everything as it is, but select the "scatter file"

That file is in the correct firmware for your phone.

Comment: Mediatek SP Flash Tool can not flash HiSilicon Kirin chipset